# Pipeline releases in azure devops (Web App Service) deployed in wrong folder

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

When releasing an new update for my web app service with azure devops the code is not showing in the `wwwroot` directory but its placed in a subfolder `/s/`

Problem:
https://i.ibb.co/MVjXG73/pasted-Image.png

My settings: 
https://i.ibb.co/YhQd7bG/devops.png

In application settings i added:
SCM_TARGET_PATH = D:\home\site\wwwroot

I created a yml file with the following build:

```
trigger:
  - master

pool:
  vmImage: "Ubuntu-16.04"

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
    versionSpec: "8.x"
    displayName: "Install Node.js"

- script: |
    npm install

   displayName: "npm install"

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
    archiveType: "zip"
    archiveFile: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip"
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"
    artifactName: "drop"
```

I need the code to end up in the wwwroot directory to be published live.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you check virtual application and directories is pointing like [this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/2fb72afc1f66408b4e96aa0ed31443f47d33b308/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f425753484558302e706e67)

Comment: Yeah I got that, thanks for trying :)

Comment: Is your issue solved ?

Comment: Nop it is not  :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below line to ArchiveFiles@2 task

```
includeRootFolder: false
```